# how to get Hotmail Captcha Image

Tags: java, httpwebrequest, captcha, recaptcha, mvcrecaptcha

I am facing an issue when trying to read the Hotmail captcha image, when I put the captcha image url in my browser it shows an error message in browser:

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

**captcha image URL:**

```
https://client.hip.live.com/GetHIPData?hid=.c996cc5c878e4bed81dae63301fe752b&fid=779b48a5-cdf0-41c7-acd5-d1a825e53e6c&type=visual&hdid=0&rnd=efbd9f216e1e49f385e6a977dbd89051
```

Is there any way to read the CAPTCHA Images of the Hotmail...? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you need to get this image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go here:

```
https://client.hip.live.com/GetHIP/GetHIPAMFE/HIPAMFE?id=15022&mkt=en-US&type=visual&fid=937ba765-d38e-4608-810d-fe839c01a68d
```

This will return you javascript. From this javascript extract the `imageurl:'https://....'` property. Then send a request to this url. Single use only. If you need to get another image you will have to send another request to the first url and obtain a new captcha image url.

Obviously don't forget that this is far from official information. I have obtained it by analyzing how the website works. Don't rely on that. It could break at any moment if Microsoft decide to change their captcha image generation process.

Comment: Sir do you know how to get the fid to make this request?